# Где найти информацию о CSS (с элементами программирования)?

Tags: css

Добрый день. Видел не однократно в примерах, когда в CSS используются элементы программирования такие как For и другие... Кто знает, где можно про них почитать?
Спасибо за любую информацию.

Comment: Гуглите препроцессоры SASS(SCSS)/Stylus

Comment: +LESS к предыдущему ответу

Comment: @Etki, точно! Почему-то думал, что в LESS нет циклов.

Comment: Спасибо, а что это вообще такое? Это фреймворк компилирует как-то? Какая актуальность этого? Я просто как-то посмотрел Демо анимацию... И был удивлен, думал что я оказывается не знаю CSS =)

Comment: > Какая актуальность этого?

Очень высокая.

Представьте, что вы верстаете незаконченный шаблон. В шаблоне есть палитра, вместе с которой используются вариации цветов: чуть потемнее, чуть посветлее. В финале у вас оказывается css'ник с тремя десятками разных hex. Если после этого в шаблоне произойдут драматичные изменения - поправить ситуацию будет непросто. Если же использовать препроцессор, то эти цвета можно задать переменными (а оттенки - вычислять) во время компиляции css.

> Я просто как-то посмотрел Демо анимацию...

Это транзишены, там нет циклов.

Comment: Хм, интересно, хотя как-то не привычно, что есть такая возможность. А транзишены - это что у нас?